# Prevent float divs to start a new row. HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css, tile

I am trying to make a simple tile grid. Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="tiles">
<div class="tile25x50">1</div>
<div class="tile50x50">2</div>
<div class="tile25x50">3</div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.tiles {
width :100px;
}

.tile25x50 {
width: 50px;
height: 25px;
background-color: red;
float: left;
}

.tile50x50 {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background-color: blue;
float: left;
}
```

And the result is:

[image: 3 float divs]

My question is how can I prevent the third div to be inserted in new row and instead fill the gap?

Live demo in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FaPzN/1/).

Comment: I am not sure what type of answer you seek. You either create a simple _inflexible_ solution by using `float:right` or use javascript (masonry) for an all purpose solution that is _flexible_ but js heavy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split layout in columns if you don't need to expand items in columns, if not use something like [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/). In simple CSS you would probably ended with dozens with wrappers and javascript either way or with *one item solutions*.

Comment: I have saw masonry, but i was trying to make a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the .tile50x50 to `float:right`, it works out, but I'm not sure how much this could really be extended to include more tiles properly.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for modern browsers (includes IE10) - http://jsfiddle.net/yqkt8/
Instead of `float`, display `inline-block`, then use css columns.

```
.tiles {
    width: 100px;
    -webkit-column-width: 50px; -moz-column-width: 50px; column-width: 50px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 0; -moz-column-gap: 0; column-gap: 0;
}
.tile25x50 {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: red;
}
.tile50x50 {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change to `float:right` the float value of `.tile50x50`

```
.tile50x50 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: can you give us this exemple where it didn't work ? and we'll try to help you

Comment: Imagine if I extend .tiles to 150px and then add a couple more 25x25 tiles at the right side of the 50x50 tile. This won't work because 50x50 will be always at most right side.

Answer (score 0):

You CAN use Float: right; but that would flow differently on different browsers. I would use a table with one row and multiple columns

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="tile25x50">1</div></td>
        <td><div class="tile50x50">2</div></td>
        <td><div class="tile25x50">3</div></td>
        <td><div class="tile50x50">4</div></td>
        <td><div class="tile50x50">5</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Ive included an edit [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FaPzN/8/)

**EDIT:**

Well if you do not want to use tables, try an un-ordered list [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FaPzN/9/).

Comment: I don't think using tables is really a good idea to structure a web page due to a lot of articles written about tables vs div in constructing webpages.

Comment: You can try using un-ordered lists. If your heart is set on div's, then use the float:left and float:right. Although, if the page resizes too small, then the menu could get all messed up. I have personally had no issues with a properly formatted table and I have seem many grids that use lists when needed.

Comment: using tables will probably do the thing but it's not semantic (it is not purpose of table). Telling use unordered list is not solution because you will ended with the same problem as is the initial @FatDog47 div structure. Maybe using CSS (not oldIE compatible) properties of display: table, table-cell, table-row - but still I think it's too much work on it and loose of compatibility. And it's reallly not matter <div> vs. <ul>

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you two jQuery plugins:

- http://masonry.desandro.com/
- http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

**EDIT:**

Check out my cssdeck: http://cssdeck.com/labs/ojo7uw0l

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to change the style of .tile50x50 from float left to float right.

Comment: Please read existing answers before posting. That was [already suggested two days ago](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18066205/104223). No need to post it again.

Answer (score 0):

I just fiddled around on your fiddle file and I was able to align the `divs` in a couple steps.

First place the `div` 3 between the other two `divs`

Now for the CSS:

```
.tiles {
width :100px;
}

.tile25x50 {
width: 50px;
height: 25px;
background-color: red;
float: left;
clear: both; /* Clears both sides so the div 3 drops down */
}

.tile50x50 {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background-color: blue;
float: left;
margin-top: -25px; /* Pushes this div back up to align with the other one */
}
```

There is an easier/more flexible way to do this and that would be:

(This option also removes `float` on the 25X50 tiles making it easier to stack.)

```
<div class="your-class-here"> <!-- this div will hold the two in there without having to do negative margin values -->
   <div class="tile25x50">1</div>
   <div class="tile25x50">2</div>
</div>
<div class="tile25x50">1</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change `tile50x50` class from `float:left;` to `float:right;`:

```
.tile50x50 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
    float: right; 
}
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/LAR3x/

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the **.tile50x50** css class value float:left to float:right.

Here is the complete code -

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
.tiles {
width :100px;
}

.tile25x50 {
width: 50px;
height: 25px;
background-color: red;
float: left;
}

.tile50x50 {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background-color: blue;
float: right;

}
.clear{
clear:both;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="tiles">
<div class="tile25x50">1</div>

<div class="tile50x50">2</div>

<div class="tile25x50">3</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use Jquery or hacks like using negative margins. HTML/CSS will be just fine :)

Depending on any further layout requirements, you can do one of two things:

1) Simply remove the 50px block from the ".tiles" container, float each of them left and change the 100px width constraint of ".tiles" to 50px

fiddle.net/HHeSW/3/

**HTML**

```
<div class="tiles">
    <div class="tile25x50">1</div>
    <div class="tile25x50">3</div>
</div>
<div class="tile50x50">2</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.tiles {
    float: left;
    width:50px;
}

.tile25x50 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: red;
    float:left;
}

.tile50x50 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
}
```

2) Add a container div for each column. You can reuse the same column class for these and even drop the width constraints on ".tiles" and the column class for future flexibility :)

http://jsfiddle.net/wurwH/3/

**HTML**

```
<div class="tiles">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="tile25x50">1</div>
        <div class="tile25x50">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="tile50x50">2</div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.tiles {
    width:100px;
}

.column{
    float:left;
}

.tile25x50 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: red;
    clear:left;
}

.tile50x50 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I write HTML and CSS for this solution. I don't use table layout, float: right or position: absolute.

## HTML

```
<h1>Example 1</h1>
<div class="tiles">
    <div class="tile tile--one">1</div>
    <div class="tile tile--two">2</div>
    <div class="tile tile--one title--modified">3</div>
</div>
<h1>Example 2</h1>
<div class="tiles">
    <div class="tile tile--one">1</div>
    <div class="tile tile--two">2</div>
    <div class="tile tile--one title--modified">3</div>
    <div class="tile tile--two">2</div>
    <div class="tile tile--one">1</div>
    <div class="tile tile--two">2</div>
    <div class="tile tile--one title--modified">3</div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
*,
*:after,
*:before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
    margin: 40px 0;
}

.tiles {
    width: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.tile {
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
}

.tile--one {
    background-color: rgba(255, 20, 20, .6);
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}

.tile--two {
    background-color: rgba(20, 20, 255, .6);
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.title--modified {
    margin-top: -100px;
}
```

I hope it can help you. This is demo

[image: Prevent Float Div]

## [Demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/6183137)

Answer (score -1):

I can't actually believe people here didn't figure this out. How on the earth's sake can 3 divs with a sum width of 150px show up in a single row that accepts a width of 100px. You simply need to adjust the width in the .tiles class.

```
.tiles {
width :150px;
}

.tile25x50 {
width: 50px;
height: 25px;
background-color: red;
float: left;
}

.tile50x50 {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background-color: blue;
float: left;
}
```

Comment: Because what you did was move the 3rd div to a 3rd column and the question here is asking to put the 3rd div directly under the first div.